# Filename as Column using Data Factory V2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a lot of JSON files in Blob Storage and what I would like to do is to load the JSON files via Data factoryV2 into SQL Data Warehouse. I would like the filename in a column for each JSON file. I know how to 
do this in SSIS but I am not sure how to replicate this in Data Factory.

e.g File Name: CornerShop.csv as CornerShop in the filename column in SQL Data Warehouse

Comment: Can you confirm if you are working with Azure SQL Data Warehouse?  If so, table-type parameters will not work for you .

Answer (score 3):

Firstly,please see the limitation in the [copy activity column mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#alternative-column-mapping):

- Source data store query result does not have a column name that is
  specified in the input dataset "structure" section.
- Sink data store (if with pre-defined schema) does not have a column
  name that is specified in the output dataset "structure" section.
- Either fewer columns or more columns in the "structure" of sink
  dataset than specified in the mapping.
- Duplicate mapping.

So,i don't think you could do the data transfer plus file name at one time.My idea is:

1.First use a [GetMetadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#get-a-folders-metadata) activity.  It should get the filepaths of each file you want to copy.  Use the "Child Items" in the Field list.

2.On success of GetMetaData activity, do [ForEach activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity).  For the ForEach activity's Items, pass the list of filepaths.

3.Inside the ForEach activity's Activities, place the Copy activity. Reference the iterated item by `@item()` or `@item().name`  on the blob storage source file name.

4.Meanwhile,configure the filename as a parameter into stored procedure. In the stored procedure, merge the filename into `fileName` column.

Comment: Hi @JayGong - I've answered a similar question here.  Please review and let me know what you think.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141391/using-adf-how-to-get-file-names-loaded-into-a-sql-server-table