# Azure Data Factory Copy using Variable

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am copying data from a rest api to an azure SQL database. The copy is working fine but there is a column which isn't being return within the api.

What I want to do is to add this column to the source. I've got a variable called symbol which I want to use as the source column. However, this isn't working:

[Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuE4D.gif)

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi,any progress here with your issue?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 7):

This functionality is available using the "Additional Columns" feature of the Copy Activity.

If you navigate to the "Source" area, the bottom of the page will show you an area where you can add Additional Columns.  Clicking the "New" button will let you enter a name and a value (which can be dynamic), which will be added to the output.

[image: Screen grab of copy activity]

Source(s):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, the copy activity may can't meet your requirements.Please see the error conditions in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#alternative-column-mapping):

- Source data store query result does not have a column name that is
  specified in the input dataset "structure" section.
- Sink data store (if with pre-defined schema) does not have a column
  name that is specified in the output dataset "structure" section.
- Either fewer columns or more columns in the "structure" of sink
  dataset than specified in the mapping.
- Duplicate mapping.

I think [Mapping Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) is your choice.You could add a `derived column` before the sink dataset and create a parameter named `Symbol`.

[image]

Then set the `derived column` as the value of `Symbol`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Copy Activity with a stored proc sink to do that.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141391/using-adf-how-to-get-file-names-loaded-into-a-sql-server-table/58155361#58155361) for more info.